# Use pytest fixtures returning list of values in paramterize

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I want to pass the values returned by a fixture to a pytest parametrized function. The fixture looks something like this

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture_returning_list(a, b, c, d)
    # This returns a list of tuples to be used in test function
    ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1,param2", fixture_returning_list())
def test_function(param1, param2)
```

This obviously does not work as we cannot call the fixture directly

I also tried using the fixture_returning_list as a normal function but when we call it in parameterize, it expects the values a, b, c and d

The parameters a, b, c and d comes from pytest arguments written as

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--a',
        action="store",
        help='a'
    )
    parser.addoption(
        '--b',
        action="store",
        help='b'
    )
    parser.addoption(
        '--c',
        action="store",
        help='c'
    )
    parser.addoption(
        '--d',
        action="store",
        help='d')

@pytest.fixture
def a(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--a")


@pytest.fixture
def b(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--b")


@pytest.fixture
def c(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--c")


@pytest.fixture
def d(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--d")
```

I also tried using the `fixture_returning_list` as a normal function but when we call it in parameterize, it expects the values `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`

```py
def fixture_returning_list(a, b, c, d)
    # This returns a list of tuples to be used in test function
```

Comment: when you define method `fixture_returning_list(a, b, c, d)` it does expect 4 parameters, if don't want any parameters then you don't have to put them as parameters may be like `fixture_returning_list()` , pls post more code so we understand if `a,b,c,d` are used in the method.

Comment: Yes all the 4 parameters are required and used by the function.

Comment: i don't think pytest support that, you need to work on [workaround refer this](https://miguendes.me/how-to-use-fixtures-as-arguments-in-pytestmarkparametrize)